# The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data

Tags: c#, ms-access

Firstly please don't mark it as duplicate I know it's been asked multiple times here but none of the links helped me.
I am trying to access database which is located on shared drive, also both the mdb file and the folder in which it is stored have full access to everyone. I have hosted my application on two different machines.

Below is the code to connect to access DB

```
       OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    DataTable dtAttendance = new DataTable();

    try
    {

        string conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessDBPath"].ToString();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Mode= Share Deny None;Data Source= " + conStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Select EmployeeId AS UserId,AttendanceDate , format(Int(Duration/60),'0') AS Duration,format(Duration Mod  60,'0') AS Remain FROM AttendanceLogs 
                where EmployeeId =" + userid.ToString() + " and Year(AttendanceDate)="+year+" and Month(AttendanceDate)="+month+"  order by AttendanceDate desc", conn);
            dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dataAdapter.Fill(dtAttendance);
            conn.Close();
        }
     }
  catch(Exception ee)
   {}
```

Only first time when I tested it, it worked properly and thereafter it started throwing above error.

Comment: Have you closed the connection after completing your task ? 
Also try rebooting the system, it might solve it. But be aware that, everything you open a connection, closing it a must.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: before opening the connection, What is the connection state ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash the state is Closed,I checked it.

Comment: In this case there might be some user rights problem. You may find your solution here, [Microsoft Jet Database Engine Error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306269)